# SoundCloud my private track embedding returns 404

Tags: php, embed, soundcloud

When i try to embed my private track on Soundcloud it returns a 404.

The code i use is this:

```
<audio src=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/########/stream?client_id=####" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
(I am aware of the iframe embedding method SC offers but that is for a no go, design wise (too big and ugly))

Comment: as you may know, 404 means the page doesn't exist... chances are that your url is incorrect... have you tried navigating to it, simply? it should show you if and why it's failing...

Answer (score 0):

To share a private track you have to pass a secret token with the URL, you can find it in share dialog on the website. So your URL would look something like:

```
<audio src=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/########/stream?client_id=####&secret_token=#-#####" preload="auto"></audio
```

Note the addition of `&secret_token=#-#####`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it is a good idea to put your secret key in html source code?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the stream of any SoundCloud track will redirect to the mp3 source hosted on `ec-media.soundcloud.com`. A possible solution is to embed the actual mp3 link into the audio tag.

Making a call to:
`https://api.soundcloud.com/i1/tracks/{track_id}/streams?client_id={api_key}&secret_token=#-#####`

should yield something that looks like this:

```
{
hls_mp3_128_url: "https://ec-hls-media.soundcloud.com/playlist/{long-hash-key}",
rtmp_mp3_128_url: "rtmp://ec-rtmp-media.soundcloud.com/mp3{long-hash-key}",
preview_mp3_128_url: "https://ec-preview-media.sndcdn.com/preview/0/30/{long-hash-key}"
}
```

Every SoundCloud track not only has a `stream` subresource, but also an `i1` resource that displays its available streams. To date, I have only seen RTMP, HTTPS, and HLS. From there, you can use whichever link that supports your use case.

A possibly helpful node.js package: [i1-soundcloud](https://github.com/francismakes/i1-soundcloud)